# Reading a large numpy save file iteratively (i.e. with a generator) when the dtype=object

Tags: python, numpy, memory-mapped-files

I have a large numpy save file (potentially larger than fits in memory). The `dtype` is `object` (it's a numpy array of variable length numpy arrays).

> Can I avoid reading the entire file into memory? 
>   E.g. build a generator to read elements iteratively.

With standard numpy `dtypes` `np.load(filename, mmap_mode='r')` would do the trick, but you can't use `mmap_mode` with object data types.

Is there any chance I can stream bytes through a reader? Or another trick I'm not aware of?

Comment: A `numpy` array of `numpy` arrays with `dtype=object` is simply not what `numpy` was designed around handling. You might consider an entirely different approach to serializing your data.

Comment: I don't have control over the serialization process unfortunately.

Comment: Well, then I think you have little choice but to follow the advice in hpaulj's answer and figure out a way to deserialize this yourself using the raw stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic format for a non-object dtype is a header block (with shape, dtype, strides, etc), followed by a byte copy of its data buffer.

In other words something akin to this sequence:

```
In [129]: x
Out[129]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [130]: x.tostring()
Out[130]: b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00'
In [132]: np.frombuffer(__, dtype=int)
Out[132]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

But if I change the dtype to object:

```
In [134]: X = x.astype(object)
In [135]: X
Out[135]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]], dtype=object)
In [136]: X.tostring()
Out[136]: b'`\x1bO\x08p\x1bO\x08\x80\x1bO\x08\x90\x1bO\x08\xa0\x1bO\x08\xb0\x1bO\x08'
```

Those data buffer bytes point to locations in memory.  Since these are small integers they may point to the unique cached values

```
In [137]: id(1)
Out[137]: 139402080
In [138]: id(2)
Out[138]: 139402096
```

If the elements instead are arrays, they would point to those arrays stored elsewhere in memory (to the `ndarray` objects, not their databuffers).

To handle objects like this `np.save` uses pickle.  Now the pickle for a `ndarray` is its `save` string.  I don't know where the `np.save` puts those strings.  Maybe it streams in line, maybe uses pointers to points latter in the file.

You/we'd have to study the `np.save` (and function calls) to determine how this data is saved. I've looked enough to see how several arrays could be saved and loaded from a file, but haven't focused on the object dtype layout.  The relevant code is in `numpy/lib/npyio.py`, `numpy/lib/format.py`

The `format` file has a doc block about the save format.

```
np.save
   format.write_array
```

If non-object `write_array` uses  `array.tofile(fp)`.  If `object`, it uses `pickle.dump(array, fp)`

Similarly `read_array` uses `np.fromfile(fp, dtype)` and `pickle.load`.

So that means we need to delve into how the `array` `pickle.dump` is done.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take a look at numpy memmap.

From the official documentation:

> Memory-mapped files are used for accessing small segments of large files on disk, without reading the entire file into memory. NumPy’s memmap’s are array-like objects. This differs from Python’s mmap module, which uses file-like objects.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

Comment: memap reads the file in a binary fashion, returning a flat ndarray of bytes. The problem is then converting those bytes to the original form in an iterative manner, and that's not covered by numpy's memmap function.