# How to load Large .npy file (mmmap_mode="r") but got OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory

Tags: python, numpy

I want to extract a `.npy` file that is nearly 70GB in size on 64GB memory. To do this, I specified the option `mmap_mode="r"` for `numpy.load()`. However, I received the following error.

```
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

How can I handle arrays with memory smaller than the `.npy` file size?

Comment: Buy more RAM. It might solve your problem

Comment: Try using [`memmap`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48714248/11647025))

Comment: What's the statement that produces the error?  The `np.load` itself, or something after?